# Special characters decoded in my textarea (using an edit in place jQuery plugin)

Tags: jquery, html, jeditable, edit-in-place

I'm trying tu use Jeditable to edit inline some content put in textareas.
So, I call the script files:

```
<script src="js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.jeditable.autogrow.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.autogrow.js"></script>
```

Then I have a function that should send data to the server (I kept the example URL).
This fonction creates a textarea and permits the edition:

```
$(".autogrow").editable("http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/php/save.php", { 
 indicator : "<img src='img/indicator.gif'>",
 type      : "autogrow",
 submit    : 'OK',
 cancel    : 'cancel',
 tooltip   : "Click to edit...",
 onblur    : "ignore",
 event   : "dblclick",
 autogrow : {
  lineHeight : 16,
  minHeight  : 32
 }
});
```

Then, I have the data to edit thant contains HTML tags because I have to store them:

```
$data = '<div style="color:red">Foo Bar</div>';
echo '<div class="autogrow">'.htmlentities($data).'</div>';
```

The "echo" displays the "$data" content perfectly with the tags, but when I want to edit inline the DIV, a textarea is created and the following data is displayed in that textarea:

```
&lt;div style="color:red"&gt;Foo Bar&lt;div&gt;
```

instead of:

```
<div style="color:red">Foo Bar</div>
```

How can I display the right characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I didn't realise this question was asked over 2 months ago - Sorry

Have you tried using the `html_entity_decode()` function when you put the text into a text area?

The `htmlentities()` function will change things like `<` into `&lt;`, while `html_entity_decode()` should change `&lt;` into `<`

Basically a textarea will not format your HTML tags so you need to convert them yourself.

However it has been a while since I used PHP so I can't remember too well.

Answer (score -1):

Simply edit this file js/jquery.jeditable.js
go to line #:398 $.editable{} function, and add the line as in below code

```
$.editable = {
        types: {
            defaults: {
                element : function(settings, original) {
                    var input = $('<input type="hidden"></input>'); 
                    $(this).append(input);
                    return(input);
                },
                content : function(string, settings, original) {
                    string = $('<div/>').html(string).text(); // <--- Add this line                
                    $(':input:first', this).val(string);
                },
```

Thanks